# how to copy and paste file into folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I want to create a batch file which copy the content of folder and paste it into another folder. Say

```
     source: D:\backup\test
destination: D:\backup1
```

But here i want to create a subfolder into destination into which i can paste the file.

```
 @echo off
   :: variables

   echo Backing up file
   set /P source=Enter source folder:
   set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:

   set listfile=xcopy /L
   set xcopy=xcopy /S/E/V/Q/F/H

   %listfile% %source% %destination%

   echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
   pause

   %xcopy% %source% %destination%
   pause
```

Comment: Your use of the xcopy tag suggests that you already know about the `xcopy` command. That's definitely a good command to use for something like this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have created a batch file which copy the data from one folder to another. But i want to copy that data into the subfolder which i have to create using command at destination.

Comment: sorry i have pasted wrong file.... this is my batch file :- @echo off
:: variables
echo Backing up file
set /P source=Enter source folder:
set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
set listfile=xcopy /L
set xcopy=xcopy /S/E/V/Q/F/H
%listfile% %source% %destination%
echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
pause
%xcopy% %source% %destination%
pause

Comment: Please add the code to your original question so that it's easier for other people to read.

Comment: Now I'm confused by what you want. If the target directory does not exist, xcopy will create it.

Comment: how to create directory using xcopy

Comment: Right, and I'm telling you that when xcopy sees a destination that doesn't exist, it will ask if the destination is supposed to be a file or a directory. If you specify that it's a directory, xcopy will AUTOMATICALLY create it. Try it yourself.

Comment: thank u for your time... i got my ans. thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if not exist` checks to see if the directory exists. If it does not, `mkdir` creates it.

```
@echo off

echo Backing up the file
set /p source=Enter source folder: 
set /p destination=Enter destination folder: 

if not exist %destination% mkdir %destination%
set listfile=xcopy /L
set xcopy=xcopy /S/E/V/Q/F/H

%listfile% %source% %target%
echo Files listed will be copied.
pause

%xcopy% %source% %destination%
```

Answer (score 1):

That will help you maybe...

```
set FOLDER_CURRENT=%cd%
set VERSION= what u want
set FOLDER_SRC= what u want
set FOLDER_OUT= what u want
mkdir %FOLDER_OUT%

echo * Create the file xcopy_EXCLUDE.txt in order to ignore some file and directory.
echo *   - ignore all .au3 files
echo *   - ignore all .pspimage files
echo *   - ignore the \psp\ directory
echo .au3 > xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo .pspimage >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo \psp\ >> xcopy_Exclude.txt
echo * The file xcopy_EXCLUDE.txt is created.
echo.
echo * Copy files with xcopy.
xcopy "%FOLDER_SRC%" "%FOLDER_OUT%" /E /H /Y /EXCLUDE:xcopy_Exclude.txt

echo * Files and directory are copied.
echo.
echo * Delete xcopy_Exclude.txt.

del xcopy_Exclude.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this is my script which i got success..

@echo off
:: variables
echo Backing up file
set /P source=Enter source folder:
set /P destination=Enter Destination folder:
set /P Folder=Enter Folder name:
@echo folder=%folder%
mkdir %destination%\%folder%
set xcopy=xcopy /S/E/V/Q/F/H/I
%xcopy% %source% %destination%\%folder%
echo files will be copy press enter to proceed
pause
```